The number of times an event will occur over a 30-year period, given an 11% chance it will happen in any given year?
I would like to calculate how many times an event will occur over a 30-year period, given an 11% chance that it will happen in any given year. I'm not sure how to calculate this. Can somebody provide instruction?
This would be useful for financial planning. For example, I volunteer with a very small local organization that -- among other things -- provides transportation to the needy using a passenger van. In the past, they've had multiple accidents/fender-benders within months of each other; in other years, they've gone many months without a single incident. They know their average monthly probability of getting in an accident due to data collected over multiple years. But, they don't know how to project how many times they WILL get in an accident over a period of years (or an estimation with a high degree of certainty). They're interested in knowing with a high degree of certainty how often they WILL get in an accident over the course of 30 years (or, an estimation with a high level of confidence). They are less interested in knowing the probability that they'll get in an accident in a given month/year.
I'm not sure how to approach this. I have a light statistical background, but my background deals mostly with methods used to investigate questions like whether or not a drug is effective at treating a disease. I'm not familiar with concepts like Poisson distributions and considerations/ calculations for risk assessment. I understand calculating probability of an event after time has passed, but I'm not sure how to provide a definitive answer that says, "Over 30 years, we can expect n number of accidents."

The problem is somewhat ill posed in that A. you don't appear to allow for multiple occurrences in a single year and B.  you don't say anything about dependence between the years.  My guess is that you want a Poisson Distribution but that's just a guess.

As a very crude remark, if the years are independent and there is a $.89$ chance of no-event in a particular year, then there is a $.89^{30}\approx .03$ chance of no-event in $30$ years.  Is that what you were asking?

As @lulu pointed out, there are at least two ways of interpreting the problem.
(1) Each year is an independent process in which either an accident happens or it doesn't, with no allowance for multiple occurrences in a single year.  Then the total number of accidents over 30 years follows a binomial distribution with $n = 30$ and $p = 0.11$.  The probability distribution is:



#accidents
probability




$0$
$0.030318$


$1$
$0.112415$


$2$
$0.201463$


$3$
$0.232399$


$4$
$0.193883$


$5$
$0.124608$


$6$
$0.064171$


$7$
$0.027193$


$8$–$30$
$0.013550$



(2) Accidents occur at a constant mean rate, independently of the time since the last one, and allowing for multiple incidents within one year.  Then the total of accidents over 30 years follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = 0.11\times 30=3.3$.



#accidents
probability




$0$
$0.036883$


$1$
$0.121714$


$2$
$0.200829$


$3$
$0.220912$


$4$
$0.182252$


$5$
$0.120286$


$6$
$0.066158$


$7$
$0.031189$


$8$–$30$
$0.019777$


$31$–$\infty$
$6 \times 10^{-20}$



The numbers are similar because the Poisson distribution is the limiting case of the binomial distribution when the time period is divided into smaller and smaller units.
One difference is that the binomial distribution limits the total number of accidents to 30 (one per year), while the Poisson distribution theoretically allows an unlimited number.  But as noted in the table, the probability of having 31 or more accidents is too small to be concerned about.
